# jQuery: Select child element but I want to change parent?

Tags: jquery, selector, addclass, removeclass

I have question with jQuery

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#doc-new">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#doc-fav">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#doc-read">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

How to use jQuery to set active for `<li>` with `<a>` have href is *doc-read* ?

```
<ul class="tabs">
        <li><a href="#doc-new">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#doc-fav">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#doc-read">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

I can find *#doc-read* but dont know how to `addClass` to parent `<li>`.

Comment: you can use the parent class, call it $(".tabs").addClass("class")

Comment: `$("#doc-read").parent();` http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: @Matt Whipple: pretty wrong, since there is no ID specified on any anchor element! He needs to get that element by attribute, so this is possible solution... $('[href="#doc-read"]').parent().attr('class', 'active');

Comment: ok, then targeting `[href='#doc-read']`, either way this question could have been resolved by 2 minutes on Google

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"How to use jQuery to set active for `<li>` with `<a>` have id is doc-read?"*

That's not an "id", it's the "href". But anyway, you'd do this:

```
$('a[href="#doc-read"]').parent().addClass("active");
```

But if the idea is to set the li to active for whichever anchor element was just clicked then you'd do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul.tabs a").click(function() {          // when any anchor clicked
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); // remove current "active"
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");   // set "active" on parent
                                               // of clicked anchor
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tsSQq/

Comment: Thanks for your idea ! However the real problem here is I have tabs on ASP.NET project with table each tab. After page reload, I 'lost' previous tab is working with. I want to reactive tab is working before without need change tab.

Comment: @Shinichi you have to pass the current tab id across to the next page to retain the selection.

Comment: To solve the "real problem" mentioned in your comment you can use `$('a[href="#doc-read"]').parent().addClass("active");` as per the first part of my answer, or you can have your server-side code give the "active" class to the right element and not use JS for this at all.

Answer (score 2):

Give anchor tag id like "doc-read".

```
$(".tabs li").removeClass('active')
$(".tabs li").find("#doc-read").parent('li').addClass('active');
```

Give it a try here - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wA7J4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I found that query bellow and it work perfectly:

```
$('li:has(a[href="#doc-fav"])').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score -1):

just use addClass() and removeClass()

```
$(".tabs>li:eq(0)").removeClass("active");
$(".tabs>li:eq(1)").addClass("active");
```